# Query with multiple likes

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

All I see is `or_like()`. Is it possible to query two different 'likes' and both are mandatory?

```
return $this->db
  ->select('product_key.contact_email, product_key.contact_number, product_key.client_name, product_key.batch_code, product_key.status, product_key.key, payment.paymentdate, product_key.id, payment.notified')
  ->from('product_key')
  ->limit($limit,$offset)
  ->like('product_key.client_name', $filter_name)   
  ->like('product_key.status', $filter_status) //Second like ('AND LIKE' maybe?)
  ->where('status', 'purchased')
  ->select_max('paymentdate','latest_payment')
  ->join('payment', 'payment.keyid=product_key.id', 'left outer')
  ->order_by('client_name', "asc")
  ->group_by('product_key.id')
  ->get()
  ->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to `$this->db->like()`which will produce multiple `AND`s:

```
$array = array('product_key.client_name' => $filter_name, 'product_key.status' => $filter_status);
$this->db->like($array);
```

Comment: It doesn't display any error. But it should work like I enter a name and didn't enter or entered the wrong data to status so it should not output anything.

Comment: Can you echo out the query string instead of running it? There should be multiple ANDs in your LIKE statement.

Comment: `SELECT `product_key`.`contact_email`, `product_key`.`contact_number`, `product_key`.`client_name`, `product_key`.`batch_code`, `product_key`.`status`, `product_key`.`key`, `payment`.`paymentdate`, `product_key`.`id`, `payment`.`notified`, MAX(`paymentdate`) AS latest_payment
FROM (`product_key`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `payment` ON `payment`.`keyid`=`product_key`.`id`
WHERE `status` =  'purchased'
AND  `product_key`.`client_name`  LIKE '%allan%'
AND  `product_key`.`status`  LIKE '%%'
GROUP BY `product_key`.`id`
ORDER BY `client_name` asc
LIMIT 10  `

Comment: If you want both client_name and status to be mandatory, you need to check that in your controller upon post - if they're not both filled in, don't output anything. The query itself does what you want it to...

Comment: Thanks @Mudshark! I realized it just now. Haha. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just added a condition to show an alert if either or both are missing so it won't output anything. Thanks for the help guys! :)